Tensor of left Artinian algebras need not be left Artinian.
We have the following fact:
If $A$ and $B$ are left Artinian algebras over a field $K$, then $A\otimes_{K}B$ need not be left Artinian.
But, how can I actually constuct the example satisfied the statements.
